# Symfony 3 - profiling performance

Tags: php, performance, controller, symfony, profile

Is it possible to get more/deeper data about the Symfony speed/slowness than seen at the image below?

As you see it says that the "controller" process takes around 8s (in dev mode), but I would like to know more about it - what actually Symfony does in this 8 seconds. Obviously the form on the screen is a bit heavy and it takes almost 2s to render it, but that's still less than ~25% of time.

This case is among the better ones, it can go to 15-20s, but I've just caught this one on screen. I've tried milli-measuring the speed inside the controller action, but that takes just a small portion of this 8s.

I looked around but couldn't find any details on profiling it precisely. I presume it has to do with the DB objects hydrating, but can't confirm that from this screen. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [Blackfire.io](https://blackfire.io/) ? This is a product from SensioLabs - the creator of Symfony so I assume, that these two should have nice integrations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did, but I had issues with setting it up, so left it for later. I'll try again.

Comment: You can try with Xdebug. Configure it to save profiling data into file and then open it with something like KCacheGrind or WinCacheGrind.

Comment: Tnx @JakubMatczak, I will actually try first the grind, and then the blackfire. I'll post what I find.