# Add custom milestones to symfony profiler performance metrics

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I would like to log the execution time of several code blocks in my application.

Is it possible to add custom data to the symfony profiler performance tab? (See image below)

Here's some pseudo code to illustrate what I want to achieve:

```php
PerformanceProfiler::start('load foo data');

$data = $this->foo->load();

PerformanceProfiler::done('load foo data');
```

[image: performance metrics]

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237605/symfony-3-profiling-performance) does not ask for a programmatic solution, so I decided to write a new question.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler/data_collector.html

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but this seems to fulfill my needs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html#timing-the-execution-of-the-application

Answer (score 1):

Use [Symfony's Stopwatch component](https://github.com/symfony/stopwatch).

Unlike in their example, to get it to appear in the timeline, you have to inject a stopwatch as a service. So to use it in a controller, you'd do something like:

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Stopwatch;

class MyController extends AbstractController
{
    public function someAction(Stopwatch $stopwatch): Response
    {
        // Giving it a category name will also give it
        // its own colour in the timeline, which is nice
        $stopwatch->start("My task's name", 'Optional category name');

        // Do the work you want to time

        $stopwatch->stop("My task's name");

        // Do anything else you want to do
    }
}
```

And of course you can inject it via the constructor in services etc.

I'm sure you're well past needing it now, but I came here looking for an answer and didn't find it, so hopefully this'll help someone else